# Electric dipole, error in calculation

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, classical-electrodynamics, dipole-moment

Currently I am calculating the dipole moment of a metal sphere in a uniform electric field $E_0$ in z-direction. From here I know that the charge density [look at page 15](http://www.phy.iitb.ac.in/~dkg/PH-102/conductors.pdf)

is given by $ 3 \epsilon_0 E_0 cos(\theta)$

Now I wanted to calculate the resulting dipole moment by $ \int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} r^3 sin(\theta) cos(\theta) 3 \epsilon_0 E_0 d\phi d\theta dr$

but in this case the integral over $\theta$ is zero and therefore this whole term will be zero which is somewhat strange, since there should be a dipole moment. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use $ 3 \epsilon_0 E_0 \cos(\theta)\delta (r-R)$ instead of $ 3 \epsilon_0 E_0 \cos(\theta)$ for charge density.

Also, the distance $r$ in the formula for dipole moment is a vector ($\mathbf{r}=r\hat{r}$):

$$\mathbf{p}=\int \mathbf{x'}\rho (\mathbf{x'})dx'$$

And the reason for the delta function in your charge density is that you have a surface charge density. Instead of that you can integrate over the surface.

Comment: but the integral over $\theta$ is still zero?

Comment: I mean vector $\mathbf{r}$ in the integral. I just modified charge density in my answer.

Comment: could you please explain the physics behind it? why is this necessary?

Comment: and what do you mean by writing r bold? a vector? but R is not a vector, so this is not actually clear to me

Comment: I do not see your point. the integral over $\theta$ will be zero.

Comment: I will explain more.

Comment: well my problem is that I do not see why this integral over theta should not be zero anymore?

Comment: Now you have $\hat{r}$ in the integral and it is a function of $\theta$.